# Oracle SQL not working on localhost after changing domain of PC and host name (PC name)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having some problems with my Oracle SQL Server 11g.

So this is what happened:
My boss told me to add my PC to our domain in our company and change the name of my PC as it was not following the convention we have. So I changed it and then when I opened SQL developer, I discover that all my connections to localhost were not working, but databases stored somewhere else in the network were perfectly accessible.

I already checked all services, restarted them and also tried to restart the computer, but nothing.

What may be the problem? Any ideas?

Thank you very much!!

(Update: I realised that the service OracleXETNSListener does not start properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Apparently when we install Oracle, there are some files which take the name of the host and use it in some scripts. 
So well, in my case, there is a file `C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/network/ADMIN/listener.ora` with this content:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOST-NAME)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

So the solution is quite easy, just change the value of HOST = MY-NEW-HOSTNAME and restart the service, should work!!

BTW, question for the experts, I would like to know why this value is not stored in a environment variable... Then we would not experience this problem!

Comment: Well, usually a host name never changes. Actually `HOST = localhost` or `HOST = 127.0.0.1` may also work. Regarding your question, when you have for example an *active* and a *stand-by* database, then you have to configure more than just one host in listener.ora file. Using just one environment variable would not be sufficient.